# Can't retrieve parameters

Tags: php, class, function, oop, object

I'm playing with OOP in PHP.

I have this code in my index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Numbers Class</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        require_once("numbers.php");
        $numbers->start("1","2","3");
        echo $numbers->list_numbers();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this in my numbers.php

```
<?php
// Class creation
class numbers
{
    private $n1, $n2, $n3;
    // Method creation
    public function start ($n1,$n2,$n3)
    {
        $this->number1=$n1; 
        $this->number2=$n2; 
        $this->number3=$n3;
    }
    public function list_numbers()
    { 
        return $this->number1;
        return $this->number2;          
        return $this->number3;
    }
}
// Object instance
$numbers=new numbers();
?>
```

Now, if what I have read so far about oop in PHP, my output should be

```
1
2
3
```

But I'm only getting

```
1
```

Why???

What I'm doing wrong???

I'm creating a new object called numbers, it has 3 attributes, I created 2 methods, one for storing the numbers and another to call them back.

I load the class and send the numbers, but somehow I'm failing when calling them back. I lost the second and third number, and I just don't understand why...

Comment: Actually, it should've echo'd `123` and not one under the other, using `echo` as `Ben Harold` stated below.

Comment: `return;` - As quoted from the PHP manual: "If called from within a function, the return statement **immediately ends execution** of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call. return will also end the execution of an eval() statement or script file." - http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Answer (score 4):

With `return` you're getting out of the function, you can use it only once per function so.
I guess what you want is the `echo` function

```
  public function list_numbers()
    { 
        echo $this->number1;
        echo $this->number2;          
        echo $this->number3;
    }
```

Comment: +1 Another option that would leave the client code in tact might be `return sprintf("%d, %d, %d", $this->number1, $this->number2, $this->number3);`

Answer (score 2):

In your `list_numbers()` method, you are `return`ing the first value. From http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

> If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call. return will also end the execution of an eval() statement or script file.

If you replaced `return` with `echo` in your `list_numbers()` method, you would get the output you are expecting.

Also, you didn't "lose" the numbers. You can verify this by doing a `var_dump($this)`.

Answer (score 1):

Antoine's and Ben's explanations are good, but the suggested repair might also be

```
public function list_numbers()
{ 
    return array($this->number1, $this->number2, $this->number3);
}
```

In this case, you get array from the function by

```
$nums = $numbers->list_numbers();
```

You can now print this array or do anything else you might want with it, the same way you would do it with any other array.

Answer (score 0):

Change to this...

```
 public function list_numbers()
{ 
    return array($this->number1, $this->number2,return $this->number3);
}
```

Then in your php file....

```
 <?php
    require_once("numbers.php");
    $numbers->start("1","2","3");
    $nums = $numbers->list_numbers();
    //use it in a loop or just print_r it or whatever....
    foreach($nums as $val){
       echo "Number is : ".$val;
    }
```